# First getting data from controller, then how to send it back? asp.net core mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have made a Asp.net core view and getting data from database is working, but I want to add adding comments option. Comments send almost properly, but while sending a comment I need to pass "samochodId" from my asp.net core model which was passed first.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label asp-for="Komentarz.Wiadomosc" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
   <div class="col-md-10">
      <input asp-for="Komentarz.Wiadomosc" class="form-control" />
         <span asp-validation-for="Komentarz.Wiadomosc" class="text-danger"></span>
         <input asp-for="Komentarz.samochodId" class="form-control" />
   </div>
</div>
```

This works, but I need to remove this line: 
`<input asp-for="Komentarz.samochodId" class="form-control" />` and do the pass automaticly by getting this Id from My model (Model.Samochod.Id) or maybe from the route?.
How Can I do this?

Comment: Could you share your model and a simple demo that could reproduce your issue?

Comment: I have added asp tag helper asp-route-id as equal to Model.Samochod.Id and it works as I want, but I'm not sure if it is a good way to solve problem like this

Comment: and I get this id this way var p = RouteData.Values["id"];

Answer (score 0):

use hidden field `<input type="hidden" asp-for="Komentarz.samochodId"  />` and make sure it's within the opening and closing of form `<form></form>` element

Comment: how can it help me?

Comment: it's null and because of that my ModelState is not valid